# How do I exclude servlet-filters from having to be serialized?

Tags: jsf, servlets, servlet-filters

I just converted my Beans to be `ViewScoped` instead of `RequestScoped`. However, since I had to add `Serialized` to those beans, I am getting two `java.io.NotSerializableException` exceptions.

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
   <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.company.rews.webclient.controller.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.company.rews.webclient.controller.MyFacesServletWrapper</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

The first place it reports this exception is somewhere inside `super.service(req, res)`:

```
public class MyFacesServletWrapper extends MyFacesServlet 
{

@Override
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;        

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");        

    try
    {   
        super.service(req, res);        
    }
    catch (ServletException e)
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();
        LoginFilter.gotoLogin(e, req, res);
    }        
}
```

}

And here at `chain.doFilter(request, response)`:

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter
{
 private static final String SYSTEM_ERROR_URI = "/login.faces";
 private static final String VIEWEX_ERROR_URI = "/login.faces";

@Override
public void doFilter( ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException
{

    HttpServletRequest  request  = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    if ( isResourceRequest(request, response) )
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    else if ( !isLoggedIn(request, response) && isLoginArea(request, response) )
    {
        gotoLogin(null, request, response);
    }
    else if( !isUserConnectedToREWS( request ) && isLoginArea(request, response) )
    {
        gotoLogin(null, request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Here is the complete error report:

```
08.05.2013. 18:03:47 org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl serializeView
SEVERE: Exiting serializeView - Could not serialize state: org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.serializeView(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:390)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedViewInServletSession(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:240)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedView(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:872)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.saveState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:144)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:195)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.renderView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:1971)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:112)
at com.mainconcept.rews.webclient.controller.MyFacesServletWrapper.service(MyFacesServletWrapper.java:30)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.company.rews.webclient.controller.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How do I exclude servlet-filters from having to be serialized if that's the problem here at all?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that `org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl` is one of your filters? It's just MyFaces' implementation of `ExternalContext` which is been used when you're running JSF on a servlet environment (instead of portlet environment). This in turn suggests that you're somewhere incorrectly assigning `ExternalContext` as a property of a backing bean which needs to be serializable.

Comment: By the way, the job which `MyFacesServletWrapper` is doing can better be done by a filter.

Comment: OK, I made class member `FacesContext` to be `transient` and now it works. I am still not sure if this is right thing to do...? Maybe I could make `FacesContext` static or...?

Comment: You should **never** make it an instance variable. It has a lifetime of one HTTP request. You should absolutely not make it an instance variable of a class which lives longer than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stop assigning `FacesContext`, `ExternalContext` and all of its artifacts as an instance variable. You should always, always obtain and assign them in thread local scope (i.e. inside the method block).

#### See also:

- [Serialize FacesContext or How to get properties-values after Server Restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265102/serialize-facescontext-or-how-to-get-properties-values-after-server-restart/)
- [java.lang.IllegalStateException at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605118/jsf2-exeptions-while-submiting-to-bean/)
- [IllegalStateException when trying to .getSessionMap() from a Session Scoped Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505488/illegalstateexception-when-trying-to-getsessionmap-from-a-session-scoped-bean/)
- [java threadlocal singleton - what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137860/java-threadlocal-singleton-what-is-it/)

---

Please note that this all has **nothing** to do with servlet filters.